# How to design the method when either const value or const reference should be returned?

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, overriding

I have classes like these:

```
class Base
{
    virtual const Room &getRoom() const = 0;
};

class Owner : public Base
{
    const Room &getRoom() const override
    {
        return myRoom;
    }

    Room myRoom;
};

class Renter : public Base
{
    const Room &getRoom() const override
    {
        return Room(myCity); //this will not work
    }

    City myCity;
};

void main()
{
    const auto& room = ownerOrRenter.getRoom();
}
```

This does not work because I am returning the reference of a local variable. But if I change the return type of Base::getRoom() to const Room, I will have to make a copy of Owner::myRoom every time getRoom() is called.

---

I think one solution is to change getRoom() to processRoom(void(*f)(Room)) so that the Room does not need to be returned. Just wonder if there is another way.

Comment: Rethink your design. Like why is a renter returning an empty room.

Comment: @StoryTeller Now I am thinking to use a function pointer to process the room inside the class instead of sending the room to outside. Just wonder if there is another way.

Comment: When you ask "How can", are you asking for the syntax/semantics, or do you need to give us more information on the actual problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: @franj I have clarified my question.

Answer (score 1):

Consider making the local variable you are returning static:

```cpp
class Renter : public Base
{
    const Room &getRoom() const override
    {
        static const Room myLocalRoom;
        return myLocalRoom;
    }
};
```

However, as some comments pointed out, you may also want to rethink your design.

Comment: The Room cannot be made static. I have clarified my question.

Comment: Then, you could return `std::shared_ptr<const Room>` instead of a constant reference. The shared pointer will handle ownership, so the Room object will be deleted as soon as noone is using it.